# How to combine multiple nginx proxy_pass locations into one?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've got my nginx setup working nicely, I'd just like to see if I can clean it up by combining all these locations with `proxy_pass` directives into one:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location /forgotPassword {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location /updatePassword {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location /register {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location /logout {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
        try_files $uri =404; 
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

As you can see the contents of each of them is identical, the only difference is the prefix.

Is there a logically equivalent way to DRY this up without changing the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these..

```
server {

    <..>

    location ~ ^/(api|forgotPassword|updatePassword|register|login|logout) {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    <..>

}
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks! I think I had tried something similar before but I must have messed up the regex.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while this is definitely cleaner, it incurs an unnecessary cost for using regex that the original does not. Purely for aesthetic reasons. In a file you will probably not spend much time looking at.